# Which is the smallest parameter of the polynomial of the smallest degree such that it has $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ as roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, problem-solving

Which is the smallest parameter of the polynomial of the smallest degree such that it has $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ as roots and has only integral parameters?

Since it has two different roots the it must be of degree at least $2$.

If it is of degree $2$, then it is of the form $(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})$, but this type of polynomial has parameters which are not integers.

If it is of degree $4$ then we have the polynomial $(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})(x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})(x+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})$.

It remains to examine the case where it is of degree $3$. This is where I got stuck. I don't know how to examine that case. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: What contest is this from?  Please name the contest, location/sponsor, and the date of the contest.

Comment: I'm sorry @amWhy but I don't have this information. My father gave me an old leaflet from from his days which I am working off. The only thing I know is that it writes next to it that it's from Romania

Comment: It doesn't even say the year :) but I can only assume that it's from the 1960s

Comment: I asked you a similar question about a former contest question you asked, and you gave me the same line then.

Comment: @amWhy yes I did give you the same answer, as it is from the same leaflet

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why someone has voted to close this question?

Comment: Please take a photo or scan of the question, and post it.

Comment: @amWhy sure thing just give me a few minutes to upload

Comment: @MichaelBlane What is the "smallest parameter of the polynomial"?

Comment: @amWhy https://ibb.co/7t90vLW

Comment: @PierreCarre If you have a polynomial of degree two say $ax^2+bx+c$, then the smallest parameter is min{a,b,c}

Comment: @MichaelBlane Then I don't see how there can be an answer to this question... any polynomial of the form $p(x)= \alpha (x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})$ has those two roots, and you can make $\alpha$ as small as you wish. Maybe you want the coefficients to be rational?

Comment: @PierreCarre yes, but $a, b, c$ need to be integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial with integer coefficients with least degree that has $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ as a root is $4 x^2 - 3$.

Every polynomial with rational coefficients that has $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ as a root is a rational polynomial multiple of $4 x^2 - 3$.

Likewise, for $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$, the polynomial is $9 x^2 - 2$.

Since these two polynomials are coprime, every polynomial with rational coefficients that has $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ as roots is a multiple of $(4 x^2 - 3)(9 x^2 - 2)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Let $f$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Then if $a+\sqrt b$ is a root of $f$, where $a, b \in \Bbb Q, \sqrt b \notin \Bbb Q$, then $a-\sqrt b$ is also a root of $f$.

Comment: ... unless $b$ is a perfect square

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Uh, yeah. Sorry.